# Firestore Security Rules Really Spaghetti-Like?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

while working on Firestore Security rules, I found out that there is no way to specify read/write-access on a Field-Level.
Everything that can be done is to specify access on a Document/Collection level.

But doesn't this enforce really weird database structures?

Consider this example:

```
[
  {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "room1",
    "color": "red",
    "owner": "Tim"
  },
  {
    "id": 642,
    "name": "room2",
    "color": "green",
    "owner": "Charles"
  },
  {
    "id": 989,
    "name": "room3",
    "color": "blue",
    "owner": "Jane"
  }
]
```

In this example I want to make it possible for e.g. Jane to read the Fields `id` `name` and `owner` of every entry in the collection, but I don't want her to see the field `color` of the rooms of the other persons.

This would be of course be possible with a data structure like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "room1",
    "owner": "Tim",
    "private_values": {
      "color": "red"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 642,
    "name": "room2",
    "private_values": {
      "color": "green"
    },
    "owner": "Charles"
  },
  {
    "id": 989,
    "name": "room3",
    "private_values": {
      "color": "blue"
    },
    "owner": "Jane"
  }
]
```

Everything I did was just move the "private"-values (in this case only the color) into another extra collection.
This way I can just set a rule for the root-object, and another extra rule on the object `private_values`.

Even though this is entirely possible to do, I wouldn't consider it especially clean when extrapolated to a bigger example where there would be for example more groups of users, who all need to be able to see different fields.

Is there a cleaner and better way to do this than the one I just explained, or is there anything else I missed?

Regards

Comment: Note that words like 'spaghetti-like', 'weird' and 'cleaner' are highly subjective. I for example see no weirdness, dirt, or pasta when separating public and private data into separate collections. I do agree that I had a steep learning curve to Firebase security rules, although in my experience that is mostly because their declarative syntax is quite different from the programming model I am (and most developers are) most familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't miss anything.  This is exactly what you're supposed to do.  Documents in Firestore are the most granular unit for operations.

Note that you can also not read a partial document (you must read all the fields if you want to read any of the fields).  If you write a Cloud Function that triggers when a document changes, you always receive the contents of the entire document, and you can't write a trigger for when an individual field changes.

Comment: Okay, thanks.

Another thought on that: Would it be better to work with references here? And how do they interact specifically with the Security-Rules? Would a reference be regarded as a simple field and thus be also read whenever the document is read, or does it count as an extra document which I have to specify myself?

Comment: A reference is just a field that contains a path to a document.